# MSTest does not create test deployment folder and test results if all tests pass

Tags: c#, mstest

I am using [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(VS.80).aspx) to test my C# code.

The problem is that, when running tests, I also write some files in the test output directory:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething() {
  // Do some Assert stuff here...

  TestContext context = GetContext();
  string folderPath = Path.GetFullPath(context.DeploymentDirectory);
  string filePath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetFullPath(this.context.TestRunDirectory), 
      "myfile.txt");

  using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath)) {
    writer.Write(content);
  }
}
```

My solution is in `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\MySolution`.

#### When failing

When I run tests and they fail, I can see folder `MySolution\TestResults\Deploy_myuser 2015-10-23 21_12_51` folder being created, **there is no `.trx` file**! But **there is `MySolution\TestResults\Deploy_myuser 2015-10-23 21_12_51\Out\myfile.txt`**!

#### When passing

No folder is created.

### My question

I want to always generate the test results folder. I do not care if the `.trx` file is not generated when passing (as long as it is when failing), but I would like to always have `myfile.txt` written in the test folder.

How to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Where you have placed above code?

Comment: It is in the final part of one of the test methods. However I did debug it and that code is reached, every line executed and the file correctly written in the destination path. However `MSTest` removes the folder when the test passes, that is why there is nothing in the end :(

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `.testsettings` file and set a property in it to deploy tests. The process you described here is called deployment. When you don't deploy the test then `mstest` will not create an addition working directory. It will just execute your test assembly from its build drop location. `.testsettings` can be used with both Visual Studio test execution and from `cmd`.

For more information refer to

> [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx)